# How Do Pressure and Temperature affect arthritis?

Tags: human-biology, joints

Here, in Houston Texas we were hit by a cold front tonight and I remembered the old saying that I'm sure you've all heard "My joints hurt, must be a storm (or change in weather) coming in". It piqued my curiosity as I wasn't sure if it was due to the temperature itself or the atmospheric pressure difference causing the flare up of pain. I looked into it and, as far as I can tell from what I've read, scientists are unable to agree on what exactly causes the flareup of pain as the evidence from the myriad of studies done on the subject are inconclusive and different in each situation. The evidence being that both temperature and atmospheric pressure changes have shown to affect flare ups in joint pain due to arthritis as well as the opposite. It almost seems like all of it can affect arthritis pain, as well as none of it. However, I began to think "What if it has nothing to do with how much the atmospheric pressure or temperature changed, or in which direction they changed? What if it's simply due to change itself?"

My source: https://www.amjmed.com/article/S0002-9343%2806%2901026-6/pdf
The article expresses that temperature drops cause pain. However, it also states that the reasons for why this occurs is unknown. I also believe temperature raises may cause this as well as I myself, along with others I've talked to with arthritis, have felt that arthritic ache in both increases and decreases of temperature. I am posting this question because I have learned that temperature is unrelated to atmospheric pressurization as both high and low temperature air may have either high or low pressures.

I'm no expert in any of the scientific fields that are involved in this question. So, what do you as the community of StackExchange Biology think?

Bonus source from SE Physics for those of you unfamiliar with temperature and atmospheric pressure: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326315/does-hot-air-have-high-pressure-and-does-compreesed-air-have-high-pressure/471775?newreg=ef5c317e3a114a3d8e4bb5fb680c477e

Comment: The first two sentences are completely unrelated to my question and only act as an, hopefully interesting, introduction into how I began to ponder my question. However, this was closed as it was deemed a personal medical question when it isn't. I am in no way asking for advice or help in my situation and just want to know how pressure and temperature affect arthritis in general. I believe my question to have been unfairly closed, or even not read fully before being closed.

Comment: I edited the question further. I would advise you to add your prior research and additional sources of the connection between arthritis  pain and weather conditions. As a sufferer from it myself, I've noticed cold has a pronounced effect, and my martial ars teacher, quite proficient in the physique of man, affirmed that notion. However, I have no knowledge about the topic whatsoever. Please add sources  and background info and perhaps the question can be re-opened.  I really like this topic btw.

Comment: Lastly, feel free to roll back my edits; but I'd advise to not put the personal background information back in, as it may trigger people thinking it's self-help. The Medical Sciences SE site may be helpful as well. We can migrate it for you (please don't cross-post).

Comment: I rolled back, but edited the post to be more-so in accordance to your advice on how to pose a question. I returned my internal ponderings as they are the questions of the post and I believe they are integral to the topic itself. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: If you believe that the SE site is a better location for this post, then by all means move it. I'm am a new user (this being my first question) so I was unsure where exactly to post it.

Comment: Meant The Medical Scientists SE. Also, I included my source and what I was able to conclude from said source.